# C# Entity Framework populate partial property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity called Person who has a collection of addresses.

I created:

```
public partial class Person
{
     public int AddressCount{get{return Addresses.Count;}}
}
```

This returns the error:

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I am returning a collection of people, how can I do this without doing this:

```
public int AddressCount
        {
            get
            {
                using (var c = new Entities())
                {
                    return c.People.Where(s => s.PersonId == PersonId).Single().Addresses.Count;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do 'this' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that this works to eager-load a "count" property without loading all the entities in the collection:

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    var people = (from p in c.People
                  select new 
                  {
                      Person = p,
                      AddressCount = p.Addresses.Count
                  }).ToList();

    foreach (var item in people)
    {
        item.Person.AddressCount = item.AddressCount;
    }
}
```

The drawback, of course, is that AddressCount needs to be settable. I guess you could give it an internal setter if your context is in the same assembly as the entity class.

You may not need the `Include("Addresses")` on there - that's worth testing. **Edit** removed it since it's not necssary (and may in fact make the query do more work than it has to).

Comment: beat me by about 15 seconds.. +1

Comment: @RPM1984 Do you remember if the Include() call is necessary?

Comment: since your *projecting* (to an anonymous type), no - it's not necessary, EF will get what it needs automatically.